# Running an application in wampserver 2.5 from another computer

Tags: php, wampserver

I don't understand why running a wampserver application remotely got so difficult. In previous version, if you put the server online, everything works perfectly. Since I installed the version 2.5 it's so complicated. My problem is this, I want to configure wampserver 2.5 so that clients in my local network  run my wampserver application installed in a hp proliant ML350e Gen8 server configured with windows server 2008 R2. I tried many times,Now I'm tired. Can you help me please?

Comment: What address is your apache server listening on? `127.0.0.1` (localhost) or `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces) Look in the apache config.

Comment: Wait please. I check

Comment: Also please note, that if this question is closed it is due to the question not being about programming, and it's probably better suited for the [`ServerFault`](http://www.serverfault.com) part of the SE network.

Comment: I tried to check in httpd.conf file. the content is strange. In the search box, I type "Listen". But I could find it. Is there any other place to check?

Comment: Apache has several configs - it might be in one of the other ones. I'm running 2.5 though, and it's in there (`httpd.conf` - Around line ~61,62): `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` (newline) `Listen [::0]:80`. Perhaps wamp botched your config when you changed the listen status and put it online? I'm not entire sure how wamp actually works internally, though I think it changes the config, saves it and then restarts apache. Is there a `httpd.conf.build` file?`

Comment: Here's what i  found: 
##Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

Comment: No I don't see the httpd.config.build file

Comment: Then it _should_ be listening on all interfaces and people should be able to connect from the outside (on your network). These people are on your _local network_ with access to your subnet, right? These listen lines are on _individual_ lines, right?

Comment: What do you mean by these lines are on individual lines?

Comment: "*Here's what i found: ##Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 0.0.0.0:80 Listen [::0]:80*". Are there new lines in this? Usually there are new lines between the listen lines, but if there isn't and they're all on one line, it'll probably be read as a comment (because of `##`)

Comment: All of them are on the same line

Comment: Then move them on individual lines. `#` means a comment. Keep `Listen 12.34.56.78:80` commented.

Comment: I did it. Nothing has changed

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Did you look at whether or not (with a network tool) it's actually listening? Did you verify the subnets and networks? Can you ping the machine?

Comment: Yes, the clients can ping the server and the server can ping the clients. the problem is when I try the same IP (server IP address) address on the browser.

Comment: Found by googling "windows listening ports": [How Can I Tell What is Listening on a TCP/IP Port in Windows?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/). If all else fails, make sure that it's allowed through the firewall. Perhaps add the apache process as an exception

Comment: The same situation, It doesn't work! I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer is configure as a single seat developer tool and therefore by default Apache is configured to accept connections from only the PC that is running WAMPServer. This is to protect the novice from accidentally allowing access to their system from the internet.

However changing it to allow access from anywhere should be quite simple. All you should need to do is as you say you did i.e. `Put Online`

What this actually does is amend a piece of the httpd.conf file from

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

To

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
```

You can manually check that that is what your httpd.conf file actually looks like now.

However a better solution in your case would be to manually edit the httpd.conf file ( using the wampmanager menus )

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

And change the above statement to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.0
```

For example, assuming that your subnet starts with those 3 quartiles.

This would allow access only form your network and not the universe as `Require all granted` would do.

Of course you would also need to add an exception to any firewall running on the PC where WAMPServer is installed so that access is not blocked on TCP port 80.

Comment: Yes, I got you. When I try this in the previous versions, It's works. In the version 2.2, 2.4 and 2.5, It  doens't work. Maybe I have to change the port and configure virtual host?

Comment: You dont have all those versions installed on the same machine at the same time do you?

Comment: Also the `Require` syntax is new to Apache 2.4, in Apache 2.2 you should use the old `Allow from 192.168.0` syntax

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna try then. In case it doesn't work, I will just reinstall the previous version.